# How to prevent a full screen double buffered app from screen freeze when debugging it?

Tags: graphics, fullscreen, doublebuffered

I'm making a full screen app that uses double buffering. The problem is a following: when I debug it and the debugger pauses the process (breakpoint hit or exception thrown), the secondary buffer may got stuck on the screen. In this case I only see the current frame and the mouse pointer and I can interact with the IDE's UI but I don't see it (because it is drawn on the primary buffer witch is not visible and I only guess where are the buttons). I think this behavior is graphics driver and OS dependent but probably I'm not the only one who has this problem (no similar problems on Ubuntu but in Windows).

Does anyone have ideas how to bring the primary buffer to front?

(ps: feel free to correct my typos and give better title if you have better idea.)

EDIT: ok, I know I can buy a new monitor or run the app in windowed mode. But my question is about the full screen mode. And I forgot to mention if I'm unable to restart my program and the 2nd buffer got stuck the only way to escape from this situation is hitting reset.

Comment: You didn't actually mention what OS and graphics driver/hardware you're using, which would probably be helpful.

Comment: OS is Windows and my graphics hardware is ATI Radeon (I'm not at home so I can't provide full model name now)

Comment: Anyway. The problem is the same on any kind of hardware and OS.

Answer (score 1):

In the olden-days, the recommended solution was two-screen debugging. Given how relatively cheap the hardware solution is, it might still be a better way to go. You'd be able to see both your program's output and the debugger at the same time, at least.

Comment: 'Cheap' is relative. :) I'm an amateur programmer with one old home PC and only one old CRT (recently replaced with an LCD though). 

There is no room for another monitor on my desk. :)

The solution I'm looking for is a software solution so how can I forcefully swap the buffers? I would write a small program for that and I would just bind the command to a hotkey. So if I'm in throuble I would just hit the hotkey and it would swap the buffers for me.